# Ricci flow reference with pictures

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, ricci-flow

I'm going to talk about **the singularities of the Ricci flow** for a group of physics students on Monday!

To create a PowerPoint, I need a text or paper that contains photos and figures to raise the intuition of the subject, because they have studied physics and understanding of abstract concepts is a bit difficult for them!!

Can someone introduce me a reference that has these features?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

There are some really fine pictures of different aspects of singularities of Ricci flows in [these lecture notes](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maseq/topping_RF_mar06.pdf)  of Peter Topping.

Good luck with your lecture!